# Laravel 5.3 model - count a column - which method is faster

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I have a Level column and need to count how many there are of each.

Which of these options are faster / more efficient and why? Or perhaps an even faster method that I didn't consider?

```
$athletes = Athlete::orderBy('level', 'desc')->get();

   foreach ($athletes as $a) {
        switch ($a->level) {
            case "advanced":
                $dataAdvanced += 1; 
                break;
            case "intermediate":
                $dataIntermediate += 1;
                break;
            case "medium":
                $dataMedium += 1;
                break;
            case "beginner":
                $dataBeginner += 1;
                break;
            case "other":
                $dataOther += 1;
                break;
        }
```

OR

```
    $dataAdvanced = Athlete::where('level', 'advanced')->count();
    $dataIntermediate = Athlete::where('level', 'intermediate')->count();
    $dataMedium = Athlete::where('level', 'medium')->count();
    $dataBeginner = Athlete::where('level', 'beginner')->count(); 
    $dataOther = Athlete::where('level', 'other')->count();
```

Comment: count(*)  gorup by level

Comment: Second one, because generic method will be faster and optimized than your customized method

Comment: Athlete::select('id', \DB::raw("count(level) as total_count"))->groupBy('level')->get();

Comment: wow, 3 people posting the exact same code ^^

Comment: you guys make it nearly impossible to choose an answer they're so pretty. The one by nithin-john gives the easiest/more readable output to work with. Thanks all - learned a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
If your table name is athletes, note: use DB in controller
$athletesInfo = DB::table('athletes')
                     ->select('level', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                     ->groupBy('level')
                     ->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is right way to count *Count(level) and  group by level*

```
 Athlete::select('id', \DB::raw("count(level) as total_count"))->groupBy('level')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

The best method is to use `group by` and `count` like:

```
$count = Athlete::groupBy('level')->select(DB::raw('count(level) as total'))->get();
```